# Циклические импорты в сериализаторе Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

У меня возникла проблема с импортом в Django, сообщение об ошибке следующее:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleEmployeeSerializers'
```

Что я делал. Мне нужно получить api вида:

**`GET /employees/`**

```
{
    "count": 12,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/employees/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "first_name": "Алена",
            "last_name": "Агапова",
            "group": "Отдел комплектации и внешней кооперации",
            "position": "Начальник отдела",
            "email": "Bectise@teleworm.us",
            "projects": [
                "Экспорт друзей VK в Google Contacts",
                "Клиент для SOAP API Почты России",
            ]
        },
        { ...
```

**`GET /projects/`**

```
{
    "count": 42,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "Экспорт друзей VK в Google Contacts",
            "number": "12-94",
            "description": "После покупки андроид-фона, появилась необходимо...",
            "project_manager": {
                "first_name": "Ирма",
                "last_name": "Капустина",
                "group": "Опытное производство",
                "position": "Начальник отдела",
                "email": "Hento1942@jourrapide.com"
            },
            "start_date": "2019-06-07",
            "finish_date": "2019-07-26"
        },
        { ...
```

Т.е. для поля `projects` в классе `employees` требуется импорт сериализатора из класса `projects`, а для поля `project_manager` в классе `projects` требуется импорт `employees`... И когда я "замыкаю круг" выскакивает ошибка.
Как мне ее разрешить?

Код сериализаторов:

**employees**

```
from projects.serializers import SimpleProjectSerializer
...
class SimpleEmployeeSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_department_title(self, obj):
        return obj.group.title

    def get_position_title(self, obj):
        return obj.position.title

    group = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_department_title')
    position = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_position_title')
    projects = SimpleProjectSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'group',
            'position',
            'email',
        )
    ...
```

**projects**

```
from organization.serializers import SimpleEmployeeSerializers
...
class SimpleProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'title',
            'finish_date',
        )
...
```

Comment: В employees у вас после объявления класса нет отступа. Это ошибка в форматировании вопроса, или же у Вас и в файле так?

Comment: Спасибо! employees поправил - немного поломалось форматирование при копи-пасте на сайт. Проблема не в этом.

Comment: Кажется проблема действительно в циклическом импорте - я раскидал по разным модулям классы сериализации и все заработало как надо.
Но мне кажется - это костыль. Возможно я концептуально не так что-то делаю?